# Multiple error messages inside of Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

When I try to launch Android studio I have these two errors [image]

Someone says if this is a big problem? For example I need to include a github project and I have some problem, can depends also for this?

Thanks to all

Comment: For the record, I have that IBus error on unrelated applications, but haven't had any issues yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether this will impact you or not is not really for us to answer.

Firstly, you have two different things here, neither of which are errors:

- An *warning* notification: "IBus prior to 1.5.11 may cause input problems.  See IDEA-78860 for details"
- An *informational* notification that updates are available for the plugins and the Android Studio platform.

The second one's irrelevant - if you want to update Android Studio and its plugins, you can, and you probably should if you want to support latest Android.  This is not an error, however, it's just a "There is an update available" notification.

The first one, though, isn't an error either, it's a warning notification about the IBus on your system being older than it would like.  To determine if it's going to impact you, you should click and read the link it actually links to in that notice, for 'IDEA-78860', to see the details of this issue, then determine if it'll impact you.

Answer (score 0):

About "IBus prior to 1.5.11 may cause input problems. See IDEA-78860 for details":
I sometimes had issues with keyboard IO being interrupted for long times... but most of the time this issue doesn't affect me. It hadn't happen for at least 3 months to me - if it will happen to you, you will know it.